# eclipse settings for editor tabs

Tags: eclipse, editing

Java class editing - In IntelliJ I am able to set preferences so only one editor tab at a time is open. I use command-O to type in the next class and only one tab stays open.

In STS (eclipse), I would like cntl-shift-R to open a new class and not leave the last class tab editor open. Only one editor tab stays open is my preference.

To be clear, I have searched extensively through the Eclipse doc and Googled for it, but I just can't find the right setting reference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse has an option to automatically close non-dirty editors. Find it in the Preferences under **General** > **Editors**, the setting is labeled *Close editors automatically*.

[image]

When you enable that, you can choose the max number of editor tabs to keep open; to satisfy your need, set it to 1.

The Help docs for that are [here](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-12.htm).